# How to correctly use a class implemented in C++/CLI as a data source for data binding in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

I defined an abstract class in VC++ like this:

```
public ref class AbstractFoo abstract {
public:
   virtual property String^ Bar {
       virtual String^ get() = 0;
   }

   // More stuff
};
```

And I have multiple concrete classes like this:

```
public ref class ConcreteFoo : AbstractFoo {
public:
    property String^ Bar {
        virtual String^ get() override;
    }
    // more
}
```

I now want to select one of several `AbstractFoo` implementations in a ComboBox in a C# application. So, I clicked the small arrow on the combo box and checked "Use Data Bound items". I then try to create a new data source with the `AbstractFoo` type. When I then click `Finish`, I get:

```
Error using the dropdown: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

When I close the dialog box, VS exits. This also happens when I use the `ConcreteFoo`.

For now, the only working solution I could come up with was to define a class in C# like this:

```
internal sealed class FooWrapper {

    private readonly AbstractFoo _foo;

    internal FooWrapper(AbstractFoo foo) {
        _foo = foo;
    }

    public String DisplayName { get { return _foo.Bar; } }

    public static implicit operator AbstractFoo(FooWrapper w) {
        return w._foo;
    }
}
```

And then add these `FooWrappers` and use the implicit conversion to get the `AbstractFoo`s back.

Is this really the only way or did I declare something wrong where VS chokes at?

EDIT: At the time the GUI is created, the `ConcreteFoo` implementations already exist.

Comment: There is no C++ here, but C++/CLI (a Microsoft extension to C++ to add .Net interop). I've changed the `C++` tag to `C++-CLI`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I did not know that there was an extra tag for this. I adapted the heading too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I investigated on this some more, and I found the cause for this problem. To my current knowledge, there is no solution but the workaround stated above.

It has to do with the managed / unmanaged interop. I am still bound to VS2010 in this project, so I do not know if this is just a bug in there or if it is a misconfiguration of things by me.

Here is how I reproduced the behaviour:

First, I created a C++/CLI class library with a very simple abstract and concrete class (let's call them `AbstractThing` and `ConcreteThing` for now). I then created a simple C# Windows Forms application, containing only a combobox which is bound to a binding source with the `AbstractThing` type. This worked.

I then added the dependencies to the unmanaged library as I always do: Specifying the include directory of the unmanaged library as an additional include directory, the directories which contain `unmanaged.lib` and `unmanaged.dll` for both debug and release modes, and add `unmanaged.lib` as an additional library. I then added a post-build command in the C# application that copies the appropriate `unmanaged.dll` into the build directory after a successful build.

Recreating the binding then still worked.

Now, on to the game-breaker:

As soon as I added an include to the unmanaged library like `#include <unmanaged.h>` I got the above error and VS exited.

To bring matters to a head, I then created such a wrapper as stated above, which worked at first, but led to the next strange error: When I re-entered the GUI designer, I got an error page that my managed/unmanaged interop DLL (the one containing `AbstractThing` and `ConcreteThing`) could not be found. The case is: .net's Data Binding analyzes the classes for public properties, and if any of them happens to be of a type that is interoperating with unmanaged stuff, things go crazy. I believe that the GUI designer and VS looks for the dependent unmanaged DLLs in the wrong directory.

So, the only feasible thing is to write a wrapper and hide the interop stuff from the data binding by doing the extraction explicitly with an internal property or a method.

So, this wrapper for the example `AbstractThing` class now works:

```
internal sealed class ThingWrapper {

    private readonly AbstractThing _thing;

    internal ThingWrapper(AbstractThing thing) {
        _thing = thing;
    }

    public String DisplayName { get { return _thing.SomeStringProperty; } }

    internal AbstractThing Thing { get { return _thing; } }
}
```

Making `internal AbstractThing Thing` property `public` causes the designer to fail to correctly load, so one cannot use the `ValueMember` property of the binding source. The extraction must be done manually as of `AbstractThing theThing = ((ThingWrapper) theComboBox.SelectedItem).Thing;`